# Why does this LINQ left join statement compile down to an SQL statement with a sub-query in EF 6?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I've been looking at the produced SQL from the join query below:

```
var leftJoin1 =
    from c in Categories
    join p in Products on c.CategoryId equals p.CategoryId into ps
    from product in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { Category = c, Product = product };
```

The above statement is an left join between a collection called Categories and Products with a 1 to many relationship between Categories and products. (ie. One category can have 0 or more products).

The above LINQ query using EF 6 produces the following SQL statement for SQL Server, as seen by using LINQPad:

```
SELECT [t0].[CategoryId], [t0].[Name], [t2].[test], [t2].[ProductId], [t2].[Name] AS [Name2], [t2].[CategoryId] AS [CategoryId2]
FROM [Category] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS [test], [t1].[ProductId], [t1].[Name], [t1].[CategoryId]
    FROM [Product] AS [t1]
) AS [t2] ON ([t0].[CategoryId]) = [t2].[CategoryId]
```

Furthermore, if you do the following LINQ query, by selecting only the product name in the select clause:

```
var leftJoin1 =
from c in Categories
join p in Products on c.CategoryId equals p.CategoryId into ps
from product in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { Category = c, Product = product.Name };
```

It will produce this SQL without the sub-query:

```
SELECT [t0].[CategoryId], [t0].[Name], [t1].[Name] AS [Product]
FROM [Category] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Product] AS [t1] ON ([t0].[CategoryId]) = [t1].[CategoryId]
```

The question is why does it need to do a sub query in the LEFT OUTER JOIN statement?

Note: I'm not interested in fixing the LINQ query to remove the inner query, I would just like to figure out why it does this.

Answer (score 0):

EF doesn't know from your query that `Category` and `Product` are related, so it will draw down the entire `Product` table in the join.

If you changed your query to use the navigational properties you wouldn't get this problem:

```
var leftJoin1 =
    from c in Categories
    select new { Category = c, Product = c.Products };
```